# Rails add_index only when first parameter not nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1. Postgres 9.3.4.

Is it possible to add an index for a particular table on multiple columns only when the first parameter in the index array is not nil?

For example, I want an evaluator to be able to submit an evaluation for a particular student's case only one time:

`add_index :evaluations, [:case_id, :evaluator_id, :student_id], unique: true, name: 'one_eval_per_case_per_evaluator'`

However, I only want the index to apply when `case_id` is not nil, since otherwise it appears as though I am getting validation errors when the other two columns match, which is not intended, since an evaluator should be able to rate a student in general, as many times as they want.

(`case_id` may also be blank, as evaluators can submit 'general evaluations', as well)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a SQL way to handle the database restriction, but I ended up adding a validation on the Rails side. Hopefully this can help someone. Basically, I check if the said parameter is nil, and if not, I perform a uniqueness validation scoped to two other fields. It looks like this:

`validates_uniqueness_of :evaluator_id, :scope => [:case_id, :trainee_id],
        :unless => Proc.new { |evaluation| evaluation.case_id.nil? }`